# SQL Insert if not exists with psycopg2

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, psycopg2

I want to insert some values in a postgres database with a python script,
but when I try it with my code below I get a syntaxerror at my first IF.

```
sql_string = "BEGIN IF (NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM table WHERE nm=name))
            BEGIN INSERT INTO table(nm, nb)
            VALUES (%s, %s) END END"
cur.execute(sql_string, (name, number))
```

Would be nice if someone has an idea.
thanks :)

Comment: There is no `IF(...)` in SQL. Put the condition in the where clause instead. : `INSERT INTO the_table(column_list) value_list WHERE NOT EXISTS (select 1 from same_table WHERE same_condition)`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109061/insert-on-duplicate-update-in-postgresql

Comment: That link refers to a different database engine.

Comment: @Dan Bracuk it's about PostgreSQL. Which is accessed from Python with psycopg2.

Answer (score 1):

This approach is database agnostic.

```
 insert into yourtable
 (field1, field2, etc)
 select distinct value1, value2, etc
 from some_small_table
 where not exists
 (subquery to check for existing records)
```